# Does haml give me the ability to reuse code in different haml files?

Tags: haml, dry, code-reuse

I looked at [the documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html) and couldn't find anything that suggested this is possible.  Here's my use case: I'm making a game and I've got 3 html files that are 90% the same.  One is used for the actual game, one is for manual testing, and one is used for automated tests.  Every time I change one, I've got to copy the change to the other two files for consistency.  I'm trying to remove this DRY violation.  Does haml give me a way to avoid copying and pasting this content to each of these files?

Comment: Some code would help us giving a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a partial file with all the common content shared between these 2 html files and then render the partial file using this notation

`= render :partial => "common_content"`

Check out more about partial files here http://haml.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I *think* this is the answer I'm looking for.  This must be a ruby concept and not a haml concept because it's not specifically mentioned in their documentation.  I am not a ruby developer and I plan on using haml without rails.  For completeness, would you mind explaining how that works? Perhaps with a snippet?

Comment: Thats actually a rails concept not a ruby. Rails allows you to create partials file which are nothing but your UI code fragments that can be reused. In Rails, All you have to do to create a partial is to create a file with the name starting with a undersore ( thats a convention you follow when u create a partial) something like _test.html.erb and the you can use that piece of code fragment or partial in you actaully template by saying = render :partial => "test"

Comment: Just wondering if you are using any other framework other than rails for your development?

Comment: Yeah I'm using [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (which I think is for node.js).  It has with a [haml plugin](https://github.com/jhchen/grunt-contrib-haml).  Other than that, I'm just generating static content.  There is no server.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263750/static-html-compilation-with-partials-using-grunt-js and see if helps. Im not a grunt expert but i am good at googling :)

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a better fit.